# Ordering generic lists does not work as intended?

Tags: c#, linq

To simplify my question, I'll will give an example.
Say I have a list of `objects` containing a `datetime` and an `integer` attribute.
I'm ordering my list items first by the `datetime` field then by the `integer` attribute.

```
Item #   Date Value  Int Value
  1      2012-01-01     0
  2      2012-01-01     4
  3      2012-01-01     6
  4      2012-01-01     13
```

Say I have those 4 items in my `list` (un-ordered at first, above is how I want it to be in the end).

I'm ordering them simply by:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(v=>v.MyDateValue).ThenBy(v=>v.MyIntValue).ToList();
```

After executing the line above, it ends up like below :

```
Item #   Date Value  Int Value
  1      2012-01-01     0
  4      2012-01-01     13
  2      2012-01-01     4
  3      2012-01-01     6
```

At first I thought it interprets my `int` value as a `string` perhaps (probably not a logical statement, just been futzing with this for quite some time) then I changed my `int` values to 10,11,12,13 but the result was still the same.

Any idea why this doesn't work ? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It appears to be sorting the int values as alphanumeric.  Are you sure your `MyIntValue` property is an `int` and not a `string`?

Comment: Are you sure that "MyIntValue" isn't mapped as a string?

Comment: Are you sure _MyDateValue_ does not have different hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: "To simplify my question, i'll be giving an example." Don't simplify your question by posting an example of the output you are getting; simplify it by posting a small complete sample program that shows the problem.

Comment: Yea I thought the same about int->alphanumeric thingy, however It's unfortunately not. I got a method, taking its enum type and returning the corresponding integer value to sort.

Comment: And all datetime value's got their "time" field set to 00:00:00

Comment: Can you provide more code (method mentioned above)? I don't see anything wrong with this at all. Just tried it myself and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: change your key selector to `v => v.DateValue.Date`, if you're not interested in the time.

I couldn't duplicate the behavior you described. The following works as expected:

```
    private class Foo
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<Foo>
                         {
                             new Foo {Date = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01), Id = 12},
                             new Foo {Date = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01), Id = 1},
                             new Foo {Date = new DateTime(2012, 01, 03), Id = 7},
                             new Foo {Date = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01), Id = 4},
                         };

        var newList = myList.OrderBy(v => v.Date).ThenBy(v => v.Id).ToList();
        foreach (var f in newList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", f.Date, f.Id);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output item order is 1, 4, 12, and 7. (7 is last because its date is later.)

I suspect that you have `DateTime` values whose `Time` is not 0.

Verify that by changing your key selector to `v => v.DateValue.Date`.

Comment: @NikolaMitev: Actually, it does work correctly. Note that the date on the item with id 7 is 2012/01/03. It's later, thus it sorts last. I even noted that in the text, which you apparently failed to read.

Comment: Well, all in all it was actually my bad. Had 2 of my items with a datetime actually containing time values. .Date, or even .Ticks has solved my issue. Thanks Jim

Comment: You mean what someone suggested 2 minutes after you posted and you said no that's not the problem? ;)